# javascript wait for a value set by another function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome plugin project and got stuck in a javascript problem(I am new to js).
here is the scenario:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    var currentTab = null;
    // this is callback and async
    chrome.tabs.query(
      {highlighted: true},
      function(tab){
        currentTab = tab[0].url;
      }
    )

    // this is not working, currentTab won't be set before used here.
    if(details.url == currentTab){
      return {cancel: false};
    }else{
      return {cancel: true};
    }
  }
)
```

so... it doesn't work obviously.
but due to the fact that I can't change how those API functions were designed, I can't re-construct them in the way that it would work easily.

both `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` and `chrome.tabs.query` don't return a value, but only accept callbacks.

and `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` will behave based on the return of the callback `{cancel: true/false}`

I tried spinning lock to create a wait barrier, but it blocks the thread and ends up been freezing the whole thing:

```
while(currentTab == null) {}  // blocks the thread, chrome.tabs.query can't even be executed, infinite loop here...
if(details.url == currentTab){
  return {cancel: false};
}else{
  return {cancel: true};
}
```

anyone knows how to hold up the return of a function based on a value set inside another function(callback) without blocking the thread?

Comment: what about using a promise?

Comment: I've thought about it and tried it too. but promise can't be the return value for ```chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener``` callback func, and also I can't ```await promise``` since that has to be inside an async function.